# Covariance of mean-reverting Vasicek process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, correlation, covariance, mean-reversion

I am dealing with a mean-reverting Vasicek process defined as:

\begin{equation}
    S_t = S_0 e^{-at} + b(1-e^{(-at)}) + \sigma e^{(-at)} \int_{0}^{t} e^{(-as)} \ W_t
\end{equation}

I want to determine the following covariance:

\begin{equation}
    Cov[(S_{t+i}),(S_{t})]
\end{equation}

Could someone help me with the analytical derivation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** We need to start with SDE:

\begin{equation}
    S_t = S_0 e^{-at} + b(1-{\rm e}^{-at}) + \sigma \int_0^t {\rm e}^{-a(t-u)}\; dW_u 
\end{equation}

As first two terms are deterministic, using standard properties of covariance, computation  of
$$ {\rm cov} (S_{t_1}, S_{t_2}) $$
can be reduced to the computation of

$$ {\rm cov} (Y_{t_1}, Y_{t_2}) $$
where

$$ Y_t = \int_0^t {\rm e}^{au}\; dW_u. $$

Last covariance calculation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913862/covariance-of-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process).

**Edit:** Once ${\rm cov} (S_{t_1}, S_{t_2})$ is available for all $t_1$ and $t_2$, [covariance properties (on linear combinations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Covariance_of_linear_combinations) can then be used again to answer the original question.

Comment: @MarkMarconi Yes. I added an edit (covariance behaviour on linear combinations of random variables).

Comment: I'm assuming your term is $S_{t+i+h} - {\rm e}^{-2ah}S_{t+i}$.